# Jquery ui how to selects tabs those are enable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs

If there are more than one tab(jquery ui tab) some of them are disable and some enable. 
How to get all enable tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ui-state-disabled') will give you all the disabled tabs.
```

It is the class added to the diabled tabs

and similarly `$('.ui-state-default:not(.ui-state-disabled)')` will give the enabled tabs.

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/424/

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use enable function

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "enable" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-state-default:not(.ui-state-disabled)')
```